# Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy" code: "3

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
window.PRINT = function() {
    $(arguments).each(function(Index,Value) {
        $('body').append(Value);
    })
};
```

And I'm getting this:

> Node cannot be inserted at the
>   specified point in the hierarchy"
>   code: "3

I'm trying to make a console.log that goes to the body.

Comment: I'm trying to print objects, like PRINT(this);  I've been working on it for a few hours now.  I'll post what I have in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
window.PRINT = function() {
    $(arguments).each(function(Index,Value) {
        $('body').append(document.createTextNode(Value));
    })
};
```

If that doesn't work add an event wrapper around your call so it loads on DOM ready or body load. You may have to wait for the body tag to be closed to write in it.